# how to access elements not read by FlaUI using UIA2 or UIA3?

Tags: automation, white-framework, flaui

How to access/Find elements not read by FLAUI using UIA2 or UIA3?
since FLAUIInspect does not show up any of the available element under the window (while inspect.exe shows all available elements) FindAll (Children/Descendants) will not give any element.

is there a wat to get these elements using FLAUI??

[image: elements in a window are not read in FLAUI]

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to access the element you need to see. On your case, the *""pane* it's a Control Type Panel inside the main window, so you gonna have to do something like this:

```
var automation = new UIA3Automation();
        var app = FlaUI.Core.Application.Attach(application.Process.Id); //Here you can attach or start a application by path
        var window = app.GetMainWindow(automation); //Get hold of the window
        var allObj = window.FindAllChildren();
        var panel = allObj.Where(x => x.AutomationId == "16386096").FirstOrDefault().FindAllChildren(); //Here you can use other property unique to the panel, I used the AutomationId for example
```

After you get hold of the panel, you can now find all the children objects.*emphasized text*

Comment: What is `application` in this case? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Melissa `application` is a Process type object, which you can retrieve in various ways, that's why I didn't put it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the `AutomationPeer` for that element which is not being found by FlaUI